# How can i add fingerprints to known_hosts from a hostlist

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a list of remote hosts and want that the fingerprints automatically added to known_hosts without i must type "yes" for every hosts.
But how?

Comment: `ssh username@hostname.com | yes` or `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@hostname.com` will not add fingerprints in known_host file

Comment: but i want, that is added to known_list, because i want to work with ansible and this is the requirement, that all hosts are known

Comment: Not correctly. Ansible needs not to have all hosts as known. You can add 
`host_key_checking = False` in your `ansible.cfg` and it will ignore uknown hosts. If you still need, use `yes` builtin: `ssh username@hostname.com | yes`. if host is unknown, command will autoadd it key.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for that:

```
ssh-keyscan -f hostlist >> known_hosts_file
```

Optionally with the `-H` option to hash the hostnames like `ssh` would do.

Comment: i tested it: "ssh-keyscan -H -f /root/hostlist >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts"
no output/not working....

Comment: You mean that no keys were added into that file ? Try it with `-v` and without the `>>` redirection; that should show some more info.

Comment: i get the error: "getaddrinfo /root/.ssh/known_hosts: Name or service not known"

Comment: I meant: `ssh-keyscan -v -f /root/hostlist`